# Produce an Array from a Lambda Function, dimension shape and dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

I need to create a function that takes a lambda, a dimension shape and the Numpy dtype, and produces an array.
I know theres the `fromfunction` that will do just that but I cant use that. I guess one way of looking at it is that I need to hardcode a `fromfunction`. The problem I'm having is that the lambda function can't be passed as its a function. Ive tried using loops and using indices and I'm new to the latter idea so I might not be doing that properly. Basically I need to create the function. The inputs are given as is the (expected) result in the comment.

```py
import numpy as np
def array_function(f, d, dtype=None):

    return x

print(array_function(lambda i,j: (i - j)**2, [4, 4]))

# Expected Result
#[[0. 1. 4. 9.]
# [1. 0. 1. 4.]
# [4. 1. 0. 1.]
# [9. 4. 1. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For this `lambda`, `fromfunction` works fine:

```
In [1]: foo = lambda i,j: (i-j)**2                                              
In [2]: np.fromfunction(foo,(4,4))                                              
Out[2]: 
array([[0., 1., 4., 9.],
       [1., 0., 1., 4.],
       [4., 1., 0., 1.],
       [9., 4., 1., 0.]])
```

`fromfunction` generates a 'grid' of indices from the shape:

```
In [7]: np.indices((4,4))                                                       
Out[7]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
```

and passes the two planes (1st dimension) to your function.  Your function, as written, works with arrays such as these 2d grids.  `meshgrid` and `mgrid` (and `ogrid`) generate similar indices.

But I could just as well create two arrays directly and pass them to `foo`:

```
In [8]: foo(np.arange(4)[:,None], np.arange(4))                                 
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 1, 4, 9],
       [1, 0, 1, 4],
       [4, 1, 0, 1],
       [9, 4, 1, 0]])
```

These two input arrays broadcast against each other just as the 2 planes in `Out[7]` do.  They are, in effect, the (4,1) and (4) shaped equivalents.

Note that in Python a `lambda` is just an anonymous function. Here I assigned it to a variable, giving a name (of sorts).  A `def` function could be used just as well.

So as long as your function works with the required 2d index arrays, you don't need any special coding.

If the function only works with scalar values of `i` and `j`, then you have to resort to something that iterates at a Python level (as opposed to using compiled `numpy` functions).

The list comprehension version:

```
In [6]: np.array([[foo(i,j) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)])              
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 1, 4, 9],
       [1, 0, 1, 4],
       [4, 1, 0, 1],
       [9, 4, 1, 0]])
```

I rather like `frompyfunc`, which would be used as:

```
In [9]: f = np.frompyfunc(foo, 2,1)                                             
In [10]: f(np.arange(4)[:,None], np.arange(4))                                  
Out[10]: 
array([[0, 1, 4, 9],
       [1, 0, 1, 4],
       [4, 1, 0, 1],
       [9, 4, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Note it returns an object dtype.  This can be modified with an `astype`.  It could also be passed to `fromfunction` if you are too 'lazy' to write your own broadcastable `I` and `J` arrays.

In my experience the `frompyfunc` approach is marginally faster than the list comprehension (upto about 2x).  On the other hand if `foo` works with arrays as in [8], then the speed ratio is more like 10x.  So performance wise you'll be happiest if you can write functions that work with whole arrays rather than scalar indices.

Answer (score 0):

> lambda function can't be passed

A lambda function is a function, which is a first-class object in python. It's no trouble to pass it as an argument to another function. You can just make a look or comprehension over the two dimensions and make and array, then reshape:

```
import numpy as np
def array_function(f, d, dtype=None):
    a = np.array([f(i, j) for i in range(d[0]) for j in range(d[1])], dtype)
    return a.reshape(d)

print(array_function(lambda i,j: (i - j)**2, [4, 4]))
```

result:

```
[[0 1 4 9]  
 [1 0 1 4]  
 [4 1 0 1]  
 [9 4 1 0]]
```

it's a little trickier if you want `array_function` to take arrays of arbitrary size. One option would be to make the array of the size and then enumerate over all the elements to call the function:

```
import numpy as np
def array_function(f, d, dtype=None):
    a = np.zeros(d)
    for coord, val in np.ndenumerate(a):
        a[coord] = f(*coord)    
    return a

# three dimensions    
print(array_function(lambda i,j, k: k+(i - j)**2, [4, 5,2], np.float))
```

**Edit based on comment**

You can build an iterator with `starmap` and `product` from itertools. I'm not sure an iterator buys you much with numpy since you usually want to know the size of the array upon creation. You can pass it a length, which isn't required but improves performance:

```
from itertools import product, starmap
import numpy as np
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

def array_function(f, d, dtype=None):
    length = reduce(mul, d)
    iterator = starmap(f, product(*[range(x) for x in d]))

    a = np.fromiter(iterator, dtype, length)
    return a.reshape(d)

print(array_function(lambda i,j: (i - j)**2, [4, 4], np.float))
```

Comment: That was educational. Also do u think we can do the same using itertools?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what itertools really buys you here, but of course you can do it. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a `np.ufunc` from your `lambda` and using `reduce` to apply it over multiple dimensions?

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np

def apply(f, shape, dtype=None):
    ufunc = np.frompyfunc(f, 2, 1)
    ranges = (np.arange(dim) for dim in shape)
    return reduce(ufunc.outer, ranges).astype(dtype)

print(apply(lambda i, j: (i - j) ** 2, (4, 4)))
```

Output:

```
[[0. 1. 4. 9.]
 [1. 0. 1. 4.]
 [4. 1. 0. 1.]
 [9. 4. 1. 0.]]
```